# Complex SQL query to join two tables

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Problem: 
Given two tables: TableA, TableB, where TableA has a one-to-many relationship with TableB, I want to retrieve all records in TableB for where the search criteria matches a certain column in TableB and return NULL for the unique TableA records for the same attribute.

Table Structures:

**Table A**

```
ID(Primary Key)      | Name          | City
1                    | ABX           | San Francisco
2                    | ASDF          | Oakland
3                    | FDFD          | New York
4                    | GFGF          | Austin
5                    | GFFFF         | San Francisco
```

**Table B**

```
ATTR_ID              |Attr_Type      | Attr_Name            | Attr_Value
1                    | TableA        | Attr_1               | Attr_Value_1
2                    | TableD        | Attr_1               | Attr_Value_2
1                    | TableA        | Attr_2               | Attr_Value_3
3                    | TableA        | Attr_4               | Attr_Value_4
9                    | TableC        | Attr_2               | Attr_Value_5
```

Table B holds attribtue names and values and is a common table used across multiple tables.  Each table is identified by Attr_Type and ATTR_ID (which maps to the IDs of different tables).
For instance, the record in Table A with ID 1 has two attributes in Table B with Attr_Names: Attr_1 and Attr_2 and so on.

**Expected Output**

```
ID                   | Name          | City             | TableB.Attr_Value
1                    | ABX           | San Francisco    | Attr_Value_1
2                    | ASDF          | Oakland          | Attr_Value_2
3                    | FDFD          | New York         | NULL
4                    | GFGF          | Austin           | NULL
5                    | GFFFF         | San Francisco    | NULL
```

**Search Criteria:**
Get rows from Table B for each record in Table A with ATTR_NAME Attr_1.  If a particular TableA record doesn't have Attr_1, return null.

**My Query**

```
select id, name, city,
    b.attr_value from table_A
    join table_B b on
    table_A.id =b.attr_id and b.attr_name='Attr_1'
```

Comment: Which flavor of SQL? MySql, Oracle TSQL, or other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a strange data structure.  You need a `left outer join` with the conditions in the `on` clause:

```
select a.id, a.name, a.city, b.attr_value
from table_A a left join
     table_B b
     on a.id = b.attr_id and b.attr_name = 'Attr_1' and b.attr_type = 'TableA';
```

I added the `attr_type` condition, because that seems logic with this data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have an sql server to test the command, but what you want is an inner/outer join query. You could do something like this

```
select id, name, city,
    b.attr_value from table_A
    join table_B b on
    table_A.id *= b.attr_id and b.attr_name *= 'Attr_1'
```

Something like this should do the trick for you